# UWP InkCanvas no "EditingMode" or "DefaultDrawingAttributes" properties

Tags: c#, react-native, inkcanvas

I am building a react-native module in c#. I want to create an InkCanvas. My XAML-File looks like that:

```
<UserControl
x:Class="InkCanvasModule.InkCanvasControl"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">

<InkCanvas x:Name="MyInkCanvas" EditingMode="Ink">

</InkCanvas>
```

However, any property like EditingMode or DefaultDrawingAttributes, as it is explained in all the c#-docs is not being found. I cant find anything on the internet, seems like I am the only person who has that error. Im feeling kinda stupid, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is your target operating system? Desktop specific (Windows and Mac OS)  or mobile OS

Comment: Desktop specific, I am developing for Windows at this time.